# Lucene not closing all files when writer.close() gets called

Tags: lucene

After `writer.close()` gets called I can delete (manually in Windows) the segment files but I cannot delete any other files associated with the index (.tvx, .tvf, etc). Windows says some other program keeps them open, but `writer.close()` should close all files associated with Lucene.

I want to delete all the files from the Lucene folder in case it exists every time I run my program.

Comment: What about the readers? Do you have any readers (or searchers) open?

Comment: What are tvx, tvf files? If they are not indexed files, IndexWriter cannot delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **lsof** (on Linux) or **Process Explorer** (on Windows) to find which process has the files open. Once you know that, you can track down why the files remain open.