# Is there a way to close all Closeables in Lucene?

Tags: lucene

When indexing, often [Lucene leaked unclosed readers, writers, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9037528).

Is there a way to just close all Closeables in Lucene at the end of each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there's none.

Lucene gives you `IndexSearcher`, `IndexReader` and `IndexWriter`. Not closing any of them will simply result file descriptor leaks and there's virtually no way around it. There are few techniques though:

1. Use [`SearcherManager`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/SearcherManager.html). This, however, still requires calling `manager.release(s)` and isn't applicable for writers/readers.
2. Extend these classes and put `.close()` call in the finalizer. And yes, I know it's dirty. But it works!
3. If you're using Java 7, you can extend these classes and implement [`AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) and use them in try-with-resources statement so closing happens automagically. Ideally all these classes should implement `AutoCloseable` themselves and hopefully they will when Lucene switches to Java 7.